# how to add javascript in laravel looping

Tags: javascript, laravel

please help me..,
I create a loop for the database input with one input affecting the other input,
when run, the first line will be successful (the input changes) but it does not happen on line two and the others ,,, this is my script..

```
@foreach($products as $product)
<tr>
<td>
    {{$product->product}}</td>
    <td class="text-center"><?php 
        if ($product->enable_stock) {
            $stock = $product->stock ? $product->stock : 0 ;
            $fstock =  (float)$stock . ' ' . $product->unit;
        } else {
            $fstock = 'N/A';
        }
   ?>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="stock" id="stock" style='width:100%; text-align:center' value= " {{$product->stock}} ">
</td>
<td>
    <input onchange="diff(this.value)" type="text" class="form-control" name="hso" id="hso" style='width:100%; text-align:center' value= " {{$product->stock}} "></td>
<td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="diff" id="diff" style='text-align:center' value="">
</td>

</tr>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function diff() {
        var stock = document.getElementById("stock").value;
        var hso = document.getElementById("hso").value;
        var diff = eval(hso) - eval(stock);
            document.getElementById("diff").value=diff;
    }
</script>
                            @endforeach
```

Comment: you are repeating the js function because it is inside your @foreach, also, you are duplicating the ID's of your inputs so it's all a mess. Assign a single id for each input and modify your js function to work with multiple id's or classes.

Comment: i originally put js outside the loop, but the same thing as this case happened ,, so i guess it's because js is outside the loop ..,
I have also tried adding $ no = $ no + 1 to each id (id = stock {{$ no}}) but the input doesn't work

Comment: When you do document.getElementById you will get only the first element, that's basic DOM knowledge. The ID's have to be different on each element. You have to adjust your js function to work with multiple ID's, maybe adding a second parameter to the function.

Answer (score -1):

```
       <?php $i=0;?>
    @foreach($products as $product)
      <?php $i++;?> 
          
    <tr>
    <td>
        {{$product->product}}</td>
        <td class="text-center"><?php 
            if ($product->enable_stock) {
                $stock = $product->stock ? $product->stock : 0 ;
                $fstock =  (float)$stock . ' ' . $product->unit;
            } else {
                $fstock = 'N/A';
            }
       ?>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="stock" id="stock{{$i}}" style='width:100%; text-align:center' value= " {{$product->stock}} ">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input onchange="diff(this.value)" type="text" class="form-control" name="hso" id="hso{{$i}}" style='width:100%; text-align:center' value= " {{$product->stock}} "></td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="diff" id="diff{{$i}}" style='text-align:center' value="">
    </td>
    
    </tr>
    <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
        function diff() {
            var stock = document.getElementById("stock{{$i}}").value;
            var hso = document.getElementById("hso{{$i}}").value;
            var diff = eval(hso) - eval(stock);
                document.getElementById("diff{{$i}}").value=diff;
        }
 });
    </script>
          
    @endforeach
```